# SQL Server how to find cooperating users in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have this problem that I haven't been able to solve yet. To keep it easy, there is this one table where all users have to enter their working hours per project.

My goal is to find all the employees that worked the most time together throughout all this years projects. I'm not interested in which projects they worked on per se, just the employees that spent most time together.

To clarify the table that I have to work with:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table-hours](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [projectid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [employeeid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [timediff] [float] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_table-hours2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Some sample data to fill this table with:

```
insert into dbo.[table-hours] (projectid, employeeid, timediff) values (1,1,2.0)
insert into dbo.[table-hours] (projectid, employeeid, timediff) values (1,2,4.0)
insert into dbo.[table-hours] (projectid, employeeid, timediff) values (1,3,1.0)
insert into dbo.[table-hours] (projectid, employeeid, timediff) values (2,1,1.0)
insert into dbo.[table-hours] (projectid, employeeid, timediff) values (2,2,3.0)
insert into dbo.[table-hours] (projectid, employeeid, timediff) values (2,4,1.0)
insert into dbo.[table-hours] (projectid, employeeid, timediff) values (3,1,1.0)
insert into dbo.[table-hours] (projectid, employeeid, timediff) values (3,3,2.0)
```

in this case the total hours per employee should be: employee 1 total hours = 2+1+1, employee 2 total hours = 4+3, employee 3 total hours = 1+2, employee 4 total hours = 1

and the shared hours are: employee 1 & 2 shared hours = 3,employee 2 & 3 shared hours = 1,employee 1 & 3 shared hours = 2,etc...

Does anyone have an idea how to bring this about?

Regards,
Johan

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results?  I don't see how you can use the table in question to determine that two employees worked together.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think the logic is simply that if two employees have records with the same project id then they have worked together. It looks hard to solve though.

Comment: @jpw . . . Each employee will have a separate row with different `timediff` values.  How would you calculate the overlap?  The minimum of these two values?

Comment: @GordonLinoff As I understood the question the timediff holds the count of hours a employee spent in a project so there would just be on row per employee and project and if two employees both have registered time in a project then they would be a pair (even though we can't know if they actually worked at the same times etc). But I'm just guessing really, only the OP knows the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ah, I feel stupid now; just realized your point about overlap, didn't get it first... I'd guess the minimum of the values.

Comment: @jpw, yes you are right! timediff is the time spent on a project. you can multiple timediff entries by the same user on the same project. the total time spend is the SUM of all entries by that employee on a project. True, with this table its not possible to know if two employee's actually worked at the same time on a project. In this case you can only know that time is spent on a project by a employee.

Answer (score 0):

There isnt an easy answer, you basically need to mine specific information from the table into a temporary table(s) which then provide the answer to your question.

The first thing you need to do is indentify all possible pairs of employees.

If all employees exist in this table, then thise logic will do it:

```
CREATE TABLE EmpPairs (ID int identity(1,1) primary key, Emp1 int, Emp2 int);

INSERT EmpPairs (Emp1, Emp2)
SELECT a.EmployeeID, b.EmployeeID
FROM (SELECT Distinct EmployeeID FROM table-hours) a CROSS JOIN 
     (SELECT Distinct EmployeeID FROM table-hours) b
WHERE a.EmployeeID <> b.EmployeeID;
```

Second you need to determine the common time for each pair of employees by project. As Gordon Linoff has suggested in his comment, this is probably best set as being the lesser of the two times. For this you'll need a query something like:

```
SELECT ep.ID 
  CASE WHEN a.TimeDiff < b.TimeDiff THEN a.TimeDiff ELSE b.TimeDiff END as [Time]
FROM table-hours a INNER JOIN table-hours b ON a.ProjectID = b.ProjectID
  INNER JOIN EmpPairs ep ON ((a.EmployeeID = ep.Emp1 and b.EmployeeID = ep.Emp2) OR
                             (b.EmployeeID = ep.Emp1 and a.EmployeeID = ep.Emp2))
```

From this you can then get your answer:

```
SELECT Emp1, Emp2, Sum([Time]) as TotalTime
FROM ( 
    SELECT ep.Emp1, ep.Emp2, 
      CASE WHEN a.TimeDiff < b.TimeDiff THEN a.TimeDiff ELSE b.TimeDiff END as [Time]
    FROM table-hours a INNER JOIN table-hours b ON a.ProjectID = b.ProjectID
      INNER JOIN EmpPairs ep ON ((a.EmployeeID = ep.Emp1 and b.EmployeeID = ep.Emp2) OR
                                 (b.EmployeeID = ep.Emp1 and a.EmployeeID = ep.Emp2))
) x
GROUP BY Emp1, Emp2
ORDER BY Sum([Time]) DESC
```

If you want just (eg) the top 10, change the first line of this to

```
SELECT TOP 10 Emp1, Emp2, Sum([Time]) as TotalTime
```

Comment: looking at this again, this could be the answer I was looking for! I will try it out on my database and will come back with the results next monday. Thanks ;)